# stdout get previous more than 1 lines from shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I am using a subproccess like this to get output from shell.

```
 with subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. /root/myFile.sh;',
                       ' func ' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as proc_launch:

        for line in proc_launch.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
```

It's giving line by line output, while I want to get output in a way like last 3 or 4 lines plus current line. Is there any method to do that in a clean way?

Comment: to recognize last 3 lines: frist  you have to get all lines to some list and later slice this list `[-3:]`

Comment: @furas can't it be done like buffer etc ? Don't want user to wait too long

Comment: list is some kind of buffer

Comment: @furas then increasing buff size dont help here ?

Comment: buffer size has nothing to do for this - `stdout` (used with `for`) always gives only one line and you have to on your own remeber this line in some list and display only [-3:] from this list.

Comment: @furas  so I got a  idea that , 1st I have to make a array , append these lines in that array and send user  array with [-3:]

Comment: yes, this should works - you use array to remeber previous lines and then you can display them with current line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand problem: you have to remember previous lines in some list and use slice `[-3:]` to display last 3 lines from this list.

```
previous_lines = list()

for line in proc_launch.stdout:
    #remeber previous lines
    previous_lines.append(line)

    # get last 3 lines with current
    text = ''.join(previous_lines[-3:])

    # display it
    print(text, end='')
```

---

BTW: you can use variable to easily change how many lines to display `[-count:]`

```
# before `for`-loop

count = 3

# inside `for`-loop

text = ''.join(previous_lines[-count:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest method would be to use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

The `maxlen` parameter is specifically designed for your use-case:

> Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added, a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end. ... They are also useful for tracking transactions and other pools of data where only the most recent activity is of interest.

A deque will be much more efficient than a perpetually increasing list, or even a fixed size list.

So:

```
from collections import deque

last_lines = deque(4)
with subprocess.Popen(...) as proc_launch:
    for line in proc_launch.stdout:
        last_lines.append(line)
        print(''.join(last_lines), end='')
```